# Jest arrow syntax causes error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, webpack-2, babel-jest

I'm setting up `Jest` for a `webpack 2` project that isn't a `React` project.

I have installed `jest-cli` and `babel-jest`.

I'm getting this error:

[image]

**.babel-rc**:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-jsx",
    ["transform-react-jsx", {"pragma": "html"}]
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          },
          'stylus-loader'
        ],
      }

    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'style.css', allChunks: true }),
  ],

  jest: {
    moduleNameMapper: {
      '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
      '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js'
    }
  },

  'env': {
    'test': {
      'plugins': ['transform-es2015-modules-commonjs']
    }
  }
}
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react",
      "stage-0"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.2",
    "eslint": "^3.17.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^19.0.2",
    "jest-cli": "^19.0.2",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.10.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^2.5.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cycle/dom": "^16.0.0",
    "@cycle/run": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.23.0",
    "bulma": "^0.3.2",
    "css-modules-require-hook": "^4.0.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx": "^0.0.2",
    "snabbdom-jsx": "^0.3.1",
    "xstream": "^10.3.0"
  }
}
```

How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: you forgot the parentheses, `() => { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `arrow function` **without parameters** still requires the parentheses.

The following code should work:

```
test('adds a and b together', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3)
})
```

Note that the only case the parentheses are not needed is when **there is only one parameter**.

You can read documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Thanks. It appears I have more errors probably unrelated to that one. `.toBe()` gives error: `sum(...).toBe is not a function` and `to.be()` gives error: `Cannot read property 'be' of undefined`

Comment: As mentioned in the [Jest Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#tobevalue), the `.toBe()` has to be called after the `expect(...)`, not inside (like I did in my answer) :)